# Command line argument passing in rosrun

Tags: rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to pass the command line arguments while running

```
  rosrun <package> <node> <parameter>
```

So that a particular block of code could be executed based on the parameter.

Below is the approach.

```
     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {  
            std::string param;
            ros::init(argc, argv, "node_name");
            ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
            ROS_INFO("Got parameter : %s", param.c_str());

            if(nh.getParam("blue", param))
            {
                 blue();    //Run program blue
            }
            else if(nh.getParam("green", param))
            {
                green();
            }
            else
            {
                 cout << "Don't run anything !! " << endl;
            }
            return 0;
       }
```

Also when I try to print the value of param it shows nothing.

Can anybody help me to fix this please.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299014/command-line-argument-passing-in-rosrun/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get the expected result by updating the code as given below.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {  
       ros::init(argc, argv, "node_name");
       std::string param;
       ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
       std::string check;
       nh.getParam("param", check);
       cout << check << endl;
       ROS_INFO("Got parameter : %s", check.c_str());

        if(check.compare("blue") == 0)
        {
          cout << check << endl;
          blue();
        }
         else if(check.compare("greeen") == 0)
        {
          cout << check << endl;
          green();
        }
        else
        {
          cout << "Control has come out !!! " << endl;
        }  
        return 0;
  }
```

command to run

```
 rosrun package node_name _param:=blue
 rosrun package node_name _param:=green
```

---

Originally posted by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) with karma: 262 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to rosrun [documentation](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun) you can do following:

```
rosrun my_package my_node _my_param:=value
```

Concrete in your case to run "blue" code should be:

```
rosrun my_package my_node _blue:=true
```

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-07-30**:
@destogl Thanks for the swift response. I will try and update you.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-07-30**:
@destogl .. Unfortunately the given method did not work.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-30**:
In your code snippet above you're printing out the value of Param before it is being set, so it will always be empty. If you move the ROS_INFO statement inside the first if then it should show the parameter value.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-07-31**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd . Thanks for the response. I was able to fix the issue and got the expected results. Will be posting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to complement, I think your original code is a bit confusing. You are expecting to have a parameter with the type "string", instead of expecting a specific value for a given parameter.

**It's important to pay attention to the return of `nh.getParam()`**. For example, if you run with `_blue:=true` or `_blue:=1`, you have `false` return because it expects to fill a string variable, not a boolean or an integer. But if you run `_blue:=some_text`, you have `true` return, because the type matches.

Just to complement, you can remove the parameter `param` or you can use it and remove `check`, it gets cleaner. I tried in my local environment and it worked like that:

```
#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {  
    std::string param;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "node_name");
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
    nh.getParam("param", param);
    ROS_INFO("Got parameter : %s", param.c_str());
    
    if(param.compare("blue") == 0)
    {
        cout << "blue " << endl;
    }
    else if(param.compare("green") == 0)
    {
        cout << "green " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Don't run anything !! " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2018-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-08-03**:
@marcoarruda Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know in this case how you would be mentioning the parameter while executing the rosrun ?

For example:

```
 rosrun my_package my_nodename _param:=blue  ??
```

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2018-08-03**:
Yes, that's exactly how I am running it.You can check in this video I recorded https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQKZEcNaVgo

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-08-03**:
@marcoarruda Thanks man. Gone through the video, it was really helpful.
In your case instead of using a separate variable name, you have used the same "param", correct ?

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2018-08-03**:
Exactly! As far as I understood, you don't need two parameters, but a single one is enough to choose a behavior in your algorithm (blue, green, yellow, etc.)
Furthermore, you can change the type of param you want to use. If you have only 2 options, you can use boolean. For more options, integer..

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-08-03**:
@marcoarruda I had more than 5 cases, so I used if else to compare strings. I have posted the approach I used as answer in this,

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add _ (underscore) before the parameter name to make it identify and remap as a variable inside the node. Adding nothing will help the ROS to identify it as a topic and remap the same.

**Syntax**

`rosrun package node _variable:=value`

`rosrun package node topic:=/topic_name`

---

Originally posted by [SS6141](https://answers.ros.org/users/37570/ss6141/) with karma: 11 on 2018-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it only works when you write this ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

---

Originally posted by [KOOYOO](https://answers.ros.org/users/38057/kooyoo/) with karma: 61 on 2019-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5